# How to change this footer object in PNAS latex template

Tags: latex

I am modifying [this PNAS template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/pnas) to be used for my own journal.  However, I don't know how to change the word of `PNAS` in the footer to my journal's name.  The `PNAS` I want to change is at the most left portion of the picture.

[image]

I searched the .tex, .cls, .sty, blg, files in the downloaded folder and could not figure out how.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Have you tried editing the string "PNAS" to what you like in line 344, or 353 or 360 in pnastwo.cls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have LaTeX installed here at the moment so I can't compile, but I advise to try editing lines 344, 353 and 360 of the file `pnastwo.cls`:

```
\theurl\hfill\footlinefont PNAS\hskip6pt  \vrule depth 2pt\hskip6pt
```

...

```
\vrule depth 2pt\hskip6pt PNAS\hskip6pt
```

...

```
\footlinefont PNAS\hskip6pt\vrule depth 2pt\hskip6pt{\foliofont\theissuedate}%
```

to:

```
\theurl\hfill\footlinefont YOURNAME\hskip6pt  \vrule depth 2pt\hskip6pt
```

...

```
\vrule depth 2pt\hskip6pt YOURNAME\hskip6pt
```

...

```
\footlinefont YOURNAME\hskip6pt\vrule depth 2pt\hskip6pt{\foliofont\theissuedate}%
```

Comment: This fixed the problem! Thanks!